# Could not locate named parameter in JPQL

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, jpql

I keep getting the following error: "could not locate named parameter [articleCommentId]" but it doesn't make sense to me because to me the named parameter is very much in place.

```
// UserV2Repository

@Query("select new com.rainbow.customer.rainbowcustomerservice.user.model.users.UserV2DtoJPQL(a.id, a.employeeId, " +
"r.name, r.id, r.position, a.userName, a.userType, a.firstName, a.lastName, a.middleName, a.emailId, " +
"a.gender, a.mobileNumber, a.parentId, u.firstName as parentIdFirstName, u.middleName as parentIdMiddleName, " +
"u.lastName as parentIdLastName) " +
"from UserV2 a inner join Role r on a.role.id=r.id left join UserV2 u on a.parentId=u.userName" +
"where ( :#{#search.firstName} is null or lower(a.firstName) like %:#{#search.firstName}%) " +
"and (:#{#search.middleName} is null or lower(a.middleName) like %:#{#search.middleName}%) " +
"and (:#{#search.lastName} is null or lower(a.lastName) like %:#{#search.lastName}%) " +
"and (:#{#search.userName} is null or lower(a.userName) like %:#{#search.userName}%) " +
"and (:#{#search.mobileNumber} is null or lower(a.mobileNumber) like %:#{#search.mobileNumber}%) " +
"and (:#{#search.roleId} is null or a.role.id = :#{#search.roleId}) " +
"and (:#{#search.gender} is null or lower(a.gender) like %:#{#search.gender}%) " +
"and (:#{#search.emailId} is null or lower(a.emailId) like %:#{#search.emailId}%)"+
"and (r.position is not null)"+
"and (:#{#search.parentId} is null or lower(a.parentId) like %:#{#search.parentId}%)")
Page\<UserV2DtoJPQL\> findUser(UserSearchRequestDto search, Pageable sort);
```

Getting the error when testing the `JPQL` code.

```
{
"timeStamp": "10-08-2023 03:36:56",
"httpStatusCode": 500,
"httpStatus": "INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR",
"reason": "INTERNAL SERVER ERROR",
"message": "COULD NOT LOCATE NAMED PARAMETER \[\_\_$SYNTHETIC$__1\], EXPECTING ONE OF \[__$SYNTHETIC$\__18, \_\_$SYNTHETIC$\__17, \_\_$SYNTHETIC$\__16, \_\_$SYNTHETIC$\__15, \_\_$SYNTHETIC$\__14, \_\_$SYNTHETIC$\__13, \_\_$SYNTHETIC$\__12, \_\_$SYNTHETIC$\__11, \_\_$SYNTHETIC$\__10, \_\_$SYNTHETIC$\__8, \_\_$SYNTHETIC$\__7, \_\_$SYNTHETIC$\__9, \_\_$SYNTHETIC$\__4, \_\_$SYNTHETIC$\__3, \_\_$SYNTHETIC$\__6, \_\_$SYNTHETIC$__5\]; NESTED EXCEPTION IS JAVA.LANG.ILLEGALARGUMENTEXCEPTION: COULD NOT LOCATE NAMED PARAMETER \[__$SYNTHETIC$__1\], EXPECTING ONE OF \[__$SYNTHETIC$\__18, \_\_$SYNTHETIC$\__17, \_\_$SYNTHETIC$\__16, \_\_$SYNTHETIC$\__15, \_\_$SYNTHETIC$\__14, \_\_$SYNTHETIC$\__13, \_\_$SYNTHETIC$\__12, \_\_$SYNTHETIC$\__11, \_\_$SYNTHETIC$\__10, \_\_$SYNTHETIC$\__8, \_\_$SYNTHETIC$\__7, \_\_$SYNTHETIC$\__9, \_\_$SYNTHETIC$\__4, \_\_$SYNTHETIC$\__3, \_\_$SYNTHETIC$\__6, \_\_$SYNTHETIC$\__5\]"
}
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.